# 301 subdomain redirect to folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I'm forced to install wordpress on a subdomain (http://lnx.domain.tld), since www points to a windows server where there are other web apps that I need not to touch.

What I wish would be a clean, seo oriented way to rewrite the url so that it appears in a subfolder http://www.domain.tld/newsite.

Any suggestion/example?

EDIT: it's just not possible to run wordpress from www

Comment: Why not something like `http://newsite.domain.tld/` ?

Comment: I'm forced by the host. http://lnx.domain.tld is the only linux space I can access.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible IF you can put a load balancer on top of your WordPress and IIS servers. You can assign your domain to it and configure it to route requests based on the URL pattern. It still depends on how flexible your hosting provider is---the load balancer needs to be able to "see" the other 2 on the network to send/route the requests.

My answer is based on experience as I had exactly the same requirements as yours. I am serving a blog and an IIS website under the same domain. I have a load balancer (HAProxy) on top of my IIS and WordPress machines. It is configured to route requests to different servers based on the URL pattern.

**Example:**

- www.website.com/blog -> Wordpress server
- www.website.com -> IIS server. (everything else / default server)

**In config, it should look something like this:**

```
# Frontends
frontend www
bind            xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
mode            http
option          httpclose
    default_backend iis_webserver

    # this is the condition
    acl blog-request path_beg -i /blog

    # route to a different machine if it's a blog
    use_backend blog_webserver if blog-request


# Backends: These are the machines that can accept requests.
backend iis_webserver
    ...settings...
    server server1 xx.xx.xx.xx:xx check
    server serverN xx.xx.xx.xx:xx check # (if you have more than one server)

backend blog_webserver 
    ...settings...
    server server1 xx.xx.xx.xx:xx check
    server serverN xx.xx.xx.xx:xx check # (if you have more than one server)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this provider is not flexible at all. I can't go even near managing something near the server.

Comment: I'm afraid that is most likely the case for hosting providers. I was only able to setup a load balancer because we have our own servers sitting on a data center.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your wordpress `root fold` at your `host wwwroot/`.
Then login your admin panel(visit:*http://www.domain.tld/newsite/wp-login.php*), in your config area, set the wordpress URL to `http://www.domain.tld/newsite` and set the site URL to `http://www.domain.tld/newsite`, too.

Comment: Unluckily this is not possible, since the www space is windows based and wordpress is unsupported there. (It's Aruba Hosting just for reference.)

Comment: @FrancescoFrapporti Oh I see.. But why not use a host that support both your main site(like asp, or jsp?) and wordpress? Amazon's service is cool! ;)

Comment: Yes, I know there are other hosts, I am even a reseller of a very cool service, but I'm dealing with Aruba now. I have to install wordpress on the lnx subdomain, but also to make it look like is installed in a subfolder of the www space.

Comment: @FrancescoFrapporti Mum..I see, but I think I can't offer more idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

@ Francesco, I think I need to clarify that your new "URL" is a sub-directory.
@ Kjuly, in this case, Francesco doesn't actually need to move his blog folder. He asks for a SEO friendly way to rewrite URL.
So the first thing comes into my mind is .htaccess 301 direction.

e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
#test sub domain
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www.)?subdomain.mydomain.com [NC]  
#avoiding repetitive redirection  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/ [NC]  
#redirect to subdirectory  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
```

Notice, if you use this method, you cannot create a directory with the name "subdomain" under //subdomain.mydomain.com/, or it can't be visit through this domain, as it's in use by someone else.

Comment: I was having my time trying to figure out why this wasn't working, then a question came up. Does this work with windows server?

Comment: Sorry Francesco, I thought that was same with on Linux. /facepalm I just move my WordPress blog from server to server. So this is totally my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another solution. Have you tried [Wordpress for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress)?

If the size of your blog is not that big, you might want to consider installing that. Then import the content.

Comment: No, it's a ecommerce.. quite complex website by now. It would be hard to make things run with windows wordpress.